# Selecting elements in a vector using a binary vector

Tags: matlab

Suppose you have a vector`a = [1 2 3 4 5]` and another vector `b = [1 0 1 1 0]`. Is there a way in which I can get the elements in 'a' which correspond to the '1' in 'b' (i.e. `ans = 1 3 4`) in MATLAB?

Comment: `a(b)` works.....

Comment: `>> a(b)
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.` This is the error.

Comment: b should be a logical, it's probably set to a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 1:5;
b = logical([1 0 1 1 0])
c = a(b);
```

Or alternatively

```
a = 1:5;
b = [1 0 1 1 0]
c = a(b == 1);
```